# google chrome problem in load images and page

Tags: google-chrome

**I use Malwarebytes to detect viruses in my laptop but after scanning, I found google chrome not worked will**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem-solving by allowing cookies in the browser